# How can I store the output of a variable with a specific index (B[i] if i = 30) for each continuous value of another variable index?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe consisting of 31 rows (index 0 to 30) and 11 variables, where the value of most variables depend on the value of the other ones. In the dataframe, the two variables of interest for this question are called p(t) and B(t). (t = time index, but that doesn't matter).

Important to note is that any value of B[t] is dependent on the initial value of p, that is, p[0]. So for example; p[0] = 20.0 --> B[30] = 1, p[0] = 20.1 --> B[30] = 3, p[0] = 20.2 --> B[30] = 5, etc.

What I would like to do is to extract the final value of B(t) (that is B[30]), for many continuous initial values of p[0]. Thereafter, I'd like to present this in a graph with B[30] on the y-axis and continuous values of p[0] on the x-axis.

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this. My current idea would be to create a for-loop that iterates over continuous values of p[0], then extract values of b[30] from the loop. Other than that I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated. I'd love to share my dataframe but I didn't manage to since I'm still a beginner in python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.